# Ember 2.8: 'Stringify' an array of objects in order to store it in a model's attributes list

Tags: arrays, ember.js

Let's say I have a model for a game, and each game has associated game cards. I would have a model like this:

Game.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    gamecards: DS.attr('string');
});
```

and in that `gamecards` attribute i would like to somehow convert an array of objects into string form in order to store it:

```
 //for simplicity, assume each empty object has card attributes like 'suit', or 'value'
 arrayOfGamecards = [//array of gamecard objects];
```

And then I could create an instance of Game which has:

```
gameCards: '[//array of gamecard objects]'
```

Ideally, I would also like to 'destringify' this array so I can do stuff with the objects inside of it. Is something like this possible with Ember?

Comment: *in order to store it* Store it where? Why do you want to represent this as a string instead of as the array which it fundamentally is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with array of plain `Ember.Object` then you don't need to create Transform you can just say `gamecards: DS.attr()`. this means EmberData will not do any transform. it will be passed through as is. so this will be enough for your current requirement.

If you have `GameCard` class, and you would like to create GameCard object from the server response.then you need to create Custom Transforms. [Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_creating-custom-transformations)

**GameCard.js**  //class definition

```
Ember.Object.extend({    
 init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    //to set the values we sent creating object
    this.set('prop1',this.get('prop1') || 'defaultvalue');
    //like this set all the properties
 }
});
```

Run the below command to create `gamecards-content` transform

`ember generate transform gamecards-content`

**app/transforms/gamecards-content.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import GameCard from './../GameCard';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  serialize: function(value) {
    return value;
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    // you can create gamecards object by using the value
    var gameCards = [];
    value.forEach((item,index) =>{
     gameCards.pushObject(GameCard.create(item));
    });
    return gameCards;
  }
});
```

**Game.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    gamecards: DS.attr('gamecards-content');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why would he store the attribute as a string and have to worry about serializing and deserializing it, instead of just storing the JS object as the value of `gamecards`?

Comment: @torazaburo In my very limited understanding of Ember, a model's attributes can only be a string, a number or a boolean. DS.attr cannot be an array or an object. If I am wrong, please correct me. I am here to learn.

Comment: @GiancarloManuelGuerraSalvá That's absolutely incorrect.

Comment: DS.attr can be array or an object . this can be achieved using `gamecards: DS.attr()`..

Comment: @kumkanillam I am reading http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#method_attr and it says that "Ember Data ships with four basic transform types: string, number, boolean and date" It also says that in order to achieve anything else I would have to employ a transform.

Comment: Do you have game-cards class to create game-card object or just Ember.Object.?.if it's plain plain Ember.Object then you dont need to specify transform and you can just say DS.attr()

Comment: @GiancarloManuelGuerraSalvá No, it says you **can** define your own transforms. You can also specify no transform at all, which means the attribute value is passed back and forth as is--an object 18 levels deep, anything you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong, or rather, it's based on a misunderstanding by the OP that he needs to store a string, and thus needs to transform it back and forth, which is very much not the case.

Comment: Everybody, I have realized that indeed my question was misguided. I have simply set up the array as another DS.attr and it worked as I expected. I thank you for your patience.

Comment: @torazaburo I updated my answer. this would be useful if we are  dealing with our own object which extends from `Ember.Object`